# Displaying perfect numbers and their adders

Tags: c, math, numbers, perfect

I need help with the program to display first 4 **perfect** numbers in the standard output and also funciton **perfect**(int,int*). Arguments of this function are natural number and the adress where you neeed to write the adders (of the perfect number I suppose). Function has to return 1 if the number is perfect, and 0 if it's not. This is what I've done so far. Help please.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int perfect(int,int*);

int main()
{
int *arr,a;
int i,j;

perfect(a,arr);
}

int perfect(int n,int *arr)
{
int lim=8128,i,sum;

for(n=1;n<=lim;n++)
{
sum=0;
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
if(n%i==0)
{
sum=sum+i;
}

}
if(n==sum)
printf("%d ",n);


}
}
```

Comment: You have a pointer which is never used. What is it supposed to be used for? On the other hand, it's good it isn't used, since it doesn't actually point anywhere.

Comment: And why do you pass `a` and `arr` to the function? Why not define `n` as a local variable inside the `perfect` function?

Comment: Arr is probably for storing all the adders of the perfect numbers, for example, adders of 6 are 1,2,3.

Comment: It seems like you're not understanding the actual assignment or exercise to begin with. Please start with that. If it's a school assignment, then please talk to your teacher or professor about it, they should be able to help you get on the right track. If this is an exercise from a book or tutorial, then please [edit] your question to include a full and complete copy-paste of the exercise text, and tell us about any doubts or thoughts you might have about the exercise.

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) Please separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code is helpful for you. The perfect function returns 1 when perfect otherwise return 0. The global array `divisor` which is used for collecting the addr. When the `perfect` function returns 1 then I print the divisor array and initiate the `deivisor_count =0`. Please have a look:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int divisor[1000], deivisor_count = 0;

int perfect(int n)
{
   int sum=0, i, j = 0;
   for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
           sum=sum+i;
           divisor[deivisor_count]= i;
           deivisor_count = deivisor_count + 1;
        }
    }
    if(n==sum){
        return 1;
    }
   
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
   
    int i, j =0, is_perfact, n=100000, k;
    
    for (i =2 ; i<=n; i++){
         deivisor_count = 0;
         is_perfact = perfect(i);
         
         if(is_perfact == 1){
             j = j + 1;
             for(k = 0; k <deivisor_count; k++){
                 printf("%d", divisor[k]);
                 if (deivisor_count -1 == k){
                     printf("=");
                 }
                 else{
                     printf("+");
                 }
             }
             printf("%d\n", i);
         }
         if (j==4){
             break;
         }
    }
   return 0;
}
```